# Bridge phone's mobile data internet connection to a WiFi network without internet connection

Tags: wi-fi, networking, mobile-data

I want to know if it is possible to basically bridge the mobile data connection of my phone to a WiFi network I am connected to where the WiFi network does not have a connection to the internet, so that the devices on the WiFi network can use the mobile data connection of the phone to access the internet.

I do not want to use a hotspot which is provided by the phone since I would like this to work automatically whenever I get in range of a device on the WiFi network and I don't want to have the phone's hotspot constantly enabled.

So basically, I want to use the phone as an internet connection for a WiFi network hosted by a different device. So, the phone would be the gateway/NAT for the WiFi network, which is hosted by a different device.

I know that it is possible on Windows since you can set a network device to use the computer's internet connection.

Is there a way to do this on Android? And if so, then how?

Comment: Possible with root. Let me know if you have a rooted device, I'll answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not currently have a rooted device, as all my previous attempts of getting root access have not been successful. I will continue try to get root access again though.

Answer (score 0):

This [Speedify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedify.speedifyandroid) app worked for me to bridge WiFi and cellular networks into a VPN profile.

Not sure how trustworthy they are though as I saw a few bad reviews online.